# Rows count that updated in Snowflake via adf dataflow activity

Tags: azure-pipelines, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have my Azure Data factory pipeline that has dataflow activity which takes data from SQL and load data to Snowflake.I have applied upsert logic that copies only the updated data. My requirement is to fetch the details of pipeline run in an audit table in Snowflake. I am using Script activity to call the Stored Procedure which is in Snowflake.
I want the total rows copied in dataflow activity. We have something called {activity('copyActivity').output.rowsCopied in copy activity but not in dataflow.

Please help me to get the count of rows copied in snowflake from SQL using adf dataflow activity.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try this for getting sink count from dataflow activity `@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.metrics.sink1.rowsWritten)`

Answer (score 0):

- I have reproduced this with a dataflow activity which copies record from source to sink.

[image]

- I created a variable called *sinkrowcount*

[image]

- Value for the variable is set using set variable activity as
  `@string(activity('dataflow2').output.runStatus.metrics.sink1.rowsWritten)`

[image]

- **Set variable activity** Output:
  [image]

Similarly, this value can be passed as a parameter for stored procedure also as per the requirement.